# Jenkins - PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins pipeline docker compose build

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace
Error

Jenkins pipeline build script
docker-compose build --no-cache

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was due to permissions issues. The following command fixed it:

```
chown -R jenkins /var/lib/jenkins/workspace
```